# Array with 2 properties, AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to save 2 Strings into an array like this:

```
array[0].name = "William"
array[0].dni = "00112233Z"
```

so i can use ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in array">
      {{item.name}}
      {{item.dni}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

But I don't know how to declare it in Angular, I keep getting this error no matter how i try: TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined.

Here's the code where I'm getting the data:

```
  $scope.array=[];
    $scope.initial = function () {
        $http.get('data/people.json').success(function (data) {
              $scope.jsonData = data;
              for(var i=0; i<$scope.jsonData.persons.length;i++){
                $scope.array[i].name=$scope.jsonData.persons[i].person.nombre;
                $scope.array[i].dni=$scope.jsonData.persons[i].person.dni;
              }
        });
    };
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set an object first inside the array to assign properties like:

```
$scope.array=[];
$scope.initial = function () {
    $http.get('data/people.json').success(function (data) {
          $scope.jsonData = data;
          for(var i=0; i<$scope.jsonData.persons.length;i++){
            $scope.array[i] = {};
            $scope.array[i].name=$scope.jsonData.persons[i].person.nombre;
            $scope.array[i].dni=$scope.jsonData.persons[i].person.dni;
          }
    });
};
```

Otherwise `array[i]` is undefined because is an empty array

Comment: Oh man it worked!! https://gyazo.com/2ae6053a0d6160629a2c0fe71bf1d4b7 thank you very much!! :D